# Hibernate with Spring Boot and Kotlin eager-loads the whole object graph

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

I have set `spring.jpa.open-in-view` to `false` and the warning is no longer appearing in the log, so that's not the cause.

The whole object graph is fetched as soon as the `find()` or `findById()` method is executed, so I don't think it's caused by serialisation either (the entities don't implement the `Serializable` interface anyway).

All the object relationships are many-to-one, and all the object mappings are annotated as lazy.

The only way I've been able to avoid eager loading was by fetching individual fields rather than whole entities, but this is time-consuming and fragile, so I'd prefer not to use this solution.

The application uses Hibernate 5.3.7 and Spring Boot 2.1.0. An older Java application we have doesn't have this problem; it uses Hibernate 4.3.8 and doesn't use Spring Boot.

Here is the code (slimmed down from the business case to try pinpoint the problem).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VT_Invoice")
class Invoice(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "InvoiceID")
    val invoiceId: Long
) {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EntityCode#ClientCore", referencedColumnName = "EntityCode#ClientCore")
    var client: Client? = null
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VT_ClientCore")
class Client(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EntityCode#ClientCore")
    val id: String
) {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EntityCode#Branch", referencedColumnName = "EntityCode#Branch")
    var branch: Branch? = null
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VT_Branch")
class Branch(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EntityCode#Branch")
    val id: String
)
```

```
interface InvoiceRepository : JpaRepository<Invoice, Long>
```

```
@Service
class InvoiceRetrievalService(
    @Autowired val invoiceRepository: InvoiceRepository
) {
    @PersistenceContext
    private lateinit var entityManager: EntityManager

    fun fetchInvoice(invoiceId: Long): Invoice {
        val hibernateInvoice = entityManager.find(Invoice::class.java, invoiceId)
        val springInvoice = invoiceRepository.findById(invoiceId)
        return hibernateInvoice
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

After debugging the Hibernate code, it turns out that eager loading is triggered by this block of code inside `DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad()`:

```
        if ( !persister.hasProxy() ) {
            return load( event, persister, keyToLoad, options );
        }
```

The `AbstractEntityPersister.hasProxy()` implementation differs between the two versions of Hibernate.

Hibernate 4.3.8:

```
    public boolean hasProxy() {
        return entityMetamodel.isLazy();
    }
```

`entityMetamodel.isLazy()` is true, so the linked object load is skipped.

Hibernate 5.3.7:

```
    public boolean hasProxy() {
        // skip proxy instantiation if entity is bytecode enhanced
        return entityMetamodel.isLazy() && !entityMetamodel.getBytecodeEnhancementMetadata().isEnhancedForLazyLoading();
    }
```

`entityMetamodel.isLazy()` is false, so the linked object is loaded. The check for bytecode enhancement turns out to be immaterial.

This is as far as I've been able to get with the investigation. I couldn't determine why the two versions of Hibernate initialise the `lazy` attribute differently; it's written to in several places, but none of the breakpoints I've set were hit, so I assume it's initialised via reflection somewhere.

Comment: Enable Hibernate logging and you can see at which point the lazy entities get initialized. Then you have some place to start debugging.

Comment: @Kayaman: Thanks. I've updated the question with what I've found during debugging.

Comment: it may be a wrongly implemented equals/hashcode/toString that is loading all your properties.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the `lazy` attribute is initialised in this block of Hibernate code:

```
lazy = persistentClass.isLazy() && (
        // TODO: this disables laziness even in non-pojo entity modes:
        !persistentClass.hasPojoRepresentation() ||
        !ReflectHelper.isFinalClass( persistentClass.getProxyInterface() )
);
```

The difference results from the `isFinalClass()` check - classes are final by default in Kotlin, but not in Java. Making the entity classes `open` fixed the problem.

On re-reading my question, I see that I forgot to mention that the older application that didn't have this problem was written in Java. I'll update the question. Sorry about that.